# Are there any cameras currently available that support encryption?

Tags: photos, camera

Are there any cameras currently available that support encryption? And I don't mean encryption of the firmware, I mean encryption of the images it stores on the memory card.

Comment: The site for this sort of thing - http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets is currently in private beta. It will be open to the public very soon

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know of any in production at the moment, but somebody's filed a patent for such a feature here:

http://www.freepatentsonline.com/5862217.html

Also, I know there are ["spy" cameras that have that feature](http://www.szprice.com/products/Mini-Spy-Digital-Video-Camera-with-Encryption-Feature_451.html), but I'm assuming you're just wanting a normal camera, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of such a thing. The only way that you can have encrypted photo's is to transfer them off the camera and on to an encrypted drive manually. Not ideal, but gets the job done.